# Using PHP in Android Webview

Tags: php, android, webview

I created an app using PHP and it runs fine using the HTTP address in the Webview object.
When using locally, the PHP script does not work (putting all files in assets).
Is there a way for PHP pages to be loaded locally but to define the actual PHP part to be used at the webserver?
To clarify, all HTML content of the .php page will be used locally but when needed PHP code it will connect the webserver.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you're asking for, that's not how PHP works: you don't send code from the browser to the server, you send results from the server to the browser. Imagine if I could send your server a bunch of PHP code to run, I could have all sorts of fun at your expense!

Comment: That is the way it already works.  Php will not execute on the device.  It finishes up on the server then sends itself along.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a php content you should have Internet connection because php codes work on server side not local devices(some apk's install mysql+php in your android device but if you want to publish your apk this way wont work in all devices on local.)

Also if you want to make an offline project why dont you use javascript "To clarify, all HTML content of the .php page will be used locally"

Here you can download phpforandroid.apk to work on the local [Click Here](https://code.google.com/p/php-for-android/)